# Show publication date in search results

Tags: 7, search

I've got a website with lots of content that has been migrated. For each node I've added the original date as the *Authored on* date. However, search snippets show the date a node was last updated.

I've read the *search-result.tpl.php* file and can't figure out how to change the `$info_split['date']` variable so that it shows the publication date instead.

How can I display the *Authored on* date instead of the updated date in the search results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a the preprocess function, [`template_preprocess_search_result()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) to add a custom *authored on* date variable to your **search-result.tpl.php** template.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  //$variables['result']['node'] is the node object returned in the search results
  //the $variables['result']['node']->created property contains the authored on date
  if(isset($variables['result']['node'])) {
    $variables['created_date'] = format_date($variables['result']['node']->created, 'short');
  }
  //$created_date will be available in your search-result.tpl.php for printing
}
```

It's probably worth mentioning that the [base template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search-result.tpl.php/7) is printing out the `$info` variable which is the concatenation of a few vars in `$info_split`. Changing `$info_split` won't change the printed date without changing **search-result.tpl.php**.

Comment: Doesn't seem to the trick, unless I'm doing something wrong. When I use `<p>Published on <?php print $created_date; ?></p>` or `<p>Published on <?php print date("jS F Y", $created_date); ?>` in search-result.tpl.php I don't get a date (just the text "Published on").

Comment: Pass by ref typo, sorry. Add the `&` operator to `$variables`.

Comment: Ah, I should have spotted that myself! It's working now - many thanks!